# Getting returned values in multiprocessing does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to control the execution of a function by checking its runtime and memory consumption. I have the following code:

```
import os
import time
import psutil
from multiprocessing import Process, SimpleQueue


def my_fun(a, b, c, q):
    l = []
    i = 2
    for _ in range(a * b * c):
        l.append(i ** 50)
        i *= 1024

    q.put((a, b, c))


def check(pid, available_mem, start_time, allowed_time, q):
    while True:
        try:
            if not psutil.pid_exists(pid):
                print('Function executed successfully')
                return True

            if psutil.virtual_memory()[1] < available_mem * (10 ** 9):
                os.kill(pid, 9)
                q.put(False)
                print('Memory usage violation')
                break

            if time.time() - start_time > allowed_time:
                os.kill(pid, 9)
                q.put(False)
                print('Time out')
                break

            time.sleep(1)

        except Exception as e:
            q.put(False)
            print(e)
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    minimum_available_memory = 5  # in GigaByte
    time_allowed = 5  # in seconds

    my_fun_q = SimpleQueue()
    check_q = SimpleQueue()
    arg1, arg2, arg3 = 1, 1, 1

    my_fun_process = Process(target=my_fun, args=(arg1, arg2, arg3, my_fun_q))
    start_time = time.time()
    my_fun_process.start()
    pid = my_fun_process.pid

    check_process = Process(target=check, args=(pid, minimum_available_memory, start_time, time_allowed, check_q))
    check_process.start()
    my_fun_process.join()
    check_process.join()

    my_fun_result = my_fun_q.get()
    check_result = check_q.get()

    print(check_result)
    if check_result:
        print(my_fun_result)
```

In my code, `my_fun()` is the function that may have high runtime or memory consumption based on the given arguments.

If the `my_fun` function is executed successfully, `check` returns `True` and `my_fun` returns a tuple of three values. But if either the runtime is higher than 5 seconds or the available memory is less than 2 GB, the corresponding process of `my_fun` is killed by the process of `check` and only the process of `check` will return `False`. This is what I expect my code to do. However,

- If `arg1, arg2, arg3 = 1, 1, 1` are passed to `my_fun`, the program prints "Function executed successfully" but gets stuck in returning the values without termination.
- If `arg1, arg2, arg3 = 100000, 100000, 100000` are passed to `my_fun`, the program prints "Time out" but again it gets stuck without returning anything or getting terminated.

This shows that the `check` function is doing its job correctly but there is something wrong with returning the values. How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add

```
    print(my_fun_q.empty(), check_q.empty())
```

before your `get()` statements, you can see what's happening.

If you call `queue.get()` and there is nothing in the queue, it's going to hang until someone adds something to the queue.  In your case, that's forever.

Your best bet would be to rewrite `check_process()` so that it *always* puts something into the queue.  True if the function succeeds and False if it doesnt.  Your code can then read from `check_q`, and depending on what it reads, optionally read from `my_fun_q`.

Comment: I changed my code and it works now. Thank you.